# fill UIBezierPath but keep path clear

Tags: objective-c, uikit, uibezierpath

Can't find solution for fill closed `UIBezierPath` with some color and some width, but keep the path line transparent.

```
[[UIColor clearColor] setStroke] does not work.
```

What i have:

[image]

What i want:

[image]

Shared line of two rectangles have same coordinates, that's why i need some shift when i draw them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is erase everything within the thick outline of a path, use `CGContextReplacePathWithStrokedPath` to convert the stroke to a path. Then fill it with a clear blend mode, thus erasing the drawing along the thick path. Alternatively, just stroke the path, again using a clear blend mode.

In this drawing, the thick yellow ellipse is not stroked or filled yellow; the ellipse is clear, and the yellow is the view behind, seen through the red rectangle. In other words, the ellipse *erases* an elliptical shape through the red rectangle.

[image]

Here's the code that drew the ellipse:

```
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(con, CGRectMake(100,100,200,50))
    CGContextSetLineWidth(con, 10)
    CGContextSetBlendMode(con, kCGBlendModeClear)
    CGContextReplacePathWithStrokedPath(con)
    CGContextFillPath(con)
```

Or you could do it this way:

```
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(con, CGRectMake(100,100,200,50))
    CGContextSetLineWidth(con, 10)
    CGContextSetBlendMode(con, kCGBlendModeClear)
    CGContextStrokePath(con)
```

Comment: When i write only [path fill], whole rect is filled, include the path. Even if i write [clearColor setStroke] and [path stroke] whole rect is still filled.

Comment: But that sounds like what you were asking to do: "fill closed path but keep path clear". Could you draw a picture of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Now i used [whiteColor setFill], but that's bad solution for many reasons.

Comment: And i should draw not only rectangles, that's why i use bezier path.

Comment: I suggest you do as I suggested in my answer - use CGContextReplacePathWithStrokedPath to get a path outlining the stroked original path - and then draw that path with blend mode of Clear, thus erasing that part of the drawing.

Comment: I've added a sample drawing plus code to show you that it works. I made my path thicker than yours, and I made it an ellipse, to show that it is just an arbitrary path.

Comment: hey @matt could you not just set the contextRef to kCGBlendModeClear, set a lineWidth, and then stroke the existing path? (without needing to make a second 'outline' path..)

Answer (score 1):

stroking with [UIColor clearColor] is not the same thing as taking an eraser to the fill you've already done, it is just drawing over it with a pen with transparent ink.

You could make a second path with pathByStrokingPath and then use an EOClip to 'mask' this area from your fill, or you can just stroke your path with whatever backgroundColor is behind...

Comment: That is a good idea too. Note that `pathByStrokingPath` is exactly the same as `CGContextReplacePathWithStrokedPath`, so you are giving the same answer I already gave. `CGContextSetBlendMode` to `kCGBlendModeClear` _does_ take an eraser to the existing fill, as my screen shot shows. Either way is fine. In my book, I illustrate both approaches (erasing vs. clipping): http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_paths_and_drawing (and the next section, on clipping)

Comment: sorry mate i did it on iPhone, couldn't see those comments (or indeed another answer) as i typed it.  The best + an upvote

Comment: No worries, your answer is good too. I was just clarifying for the OP. - There's an iPhone interface to SO????

Comment: I like when that happens. :)